# Flutter: Unable to debug to Live Device or Simulator/ Android version works

Tags: android, ios, macos, android-studio, flutter

This is the error I get while debugging Flutter app from Android Studio.

App works fine in android in both live device and emulator, but when it comes to iOS, this is what i face.

I am working on macOS Catalina (10.15.5) with XCode version 11.5 and My physical device is running on iOS Version 13.5.1 and Simulator on iOS 13.5.

All apps are pushed to Android devices and it works fine but the problem persists only with iOS.

Please help.. thanks in advance

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           732.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-06-18 02:18:53.084 xcodebuild[91466:1355893]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 5a3807b8f9f37a9db278516812a79610081c144f was NULL
    2020-06-18 02:18:53.179 xcodebuild[91466:1355892]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 5a3807b8f9f37a9db278516812a79610081c144f was NULL
    2020-06-18 02:18:53.668 xcodebuild[91466:1355892]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 5adc0eb0c458564d461badbe6dfea015d6822b24 was NULL
    2020-06-18 02:18:53.672 xcodebuild[91466:1355903]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 5adc0eb0c458564d461badbe6dfea015d6822b24 was NULL
    2020-06-18 02:19:27.169 xcodebuild[91466:1355892]  DTDeviceKit: Failed to mount DDI from '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdf5c0db8f0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'>', error=-402653183: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf5c086b50 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653183 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000001), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cab81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cea8a9 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1034
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb5e7 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 779
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55d6ec _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb27a -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 199
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011082c0c9 __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 254
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d207f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d22436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a5506c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a553818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a552f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55f957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a560097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7af9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7aeb77 start_wqthread + 15
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}
    2020-06-18 02:19:27.169 xcodebuild[91466:1355892]  iPhoneSupport: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fdf5c3581c0), iPhone, iPhone, 13.5.1 (17F80), 5a3807b8f9f37a9db278516812a79610081c144f> unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf5c086b50 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653183 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000001), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cab81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cea8a9 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1034
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb5e7 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 779
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55d6ec _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb27a -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 199
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011082c0c9 __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 254
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d207f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d22436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a5506c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a553818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a552f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55f957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a560097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7af9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7aeb77 start_wqthread + 15
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.})
    2020-06-18 02:19:42.440 xcodebuild[91466:1355903]  DTDeviceKit: Failed to mount DDI from '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdf5c0db8f0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'>', error=-402653183: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf5c2602b0 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653183 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000001), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cab81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cea8a9 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1034
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb5e7 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 779
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55da38 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 65
        5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55d5ab _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 195
        6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb27a -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 199
        7   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011082c0c9 __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 254
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d207f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d22436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a5506c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a553818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a552f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55f957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a560097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7af9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7aeb77 start_wqthread + 15
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}
    2020-06-18 02:19:42.441 xcodebuild[91466:1355903]  iPhoneSupport: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fdf5c3581c0), iPhone, iPhone, 13.5.1 (17F80), 5a3807b8f9f37a9db278516812a79610081c144f> unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf5c2602b0 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653183 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000001), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cab81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cea8a9 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1034
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb5e7 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 779
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55da38 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 65
        5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55d5ab _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 195
        6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb27a -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 199
        7   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011082c0c9 __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 254
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d207f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d22436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a5506c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a553818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a552f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55f957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a560097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7af9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7aeb77 start_wqthread + 15
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.})
    2020-06-18 02:19:57.683 xcodebuild[91466:1356057]  DTDeviceKit: Failed to mount DDI from '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdf5c0db8f0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'>', error=-402653183: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf5c22fdc0 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653183 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000001), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cab81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cea8a9 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1034
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb5e7 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 779
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55da38 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 65
        5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55d5ab _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 195
        6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb27a -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 199
        7   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011082c0c9 __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 254
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d207f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d22436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a5506c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a553818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a552f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55f957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a560097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7af9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7aeb77 start_wqthread + 15
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}
    2020-06-18 02:19:57.683 xcodebuild[91466:1356057]  iPhoneSupport: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fdf5c3581c0), iPhone, iPhone, 13.5.1 (17F80), 5a3807b8f9f37a9db278516812a79610081c144f> unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf5c22fdc0 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653183 "An unknown error occurred." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000001), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cab81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110cea8a9 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1034
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb5e7 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 779
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55da38 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 65
        5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55d5ab _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 195
        6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ceb27a -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 199
        7   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011082c0c9 __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 254
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d207f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102d22436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a5506c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a551658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a553818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a552f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a55f957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a560097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7af9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a7aeb77 start_wqthread + 15
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.})
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/MAVERICK/AndroidStudioProjects/muddledchat/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found
    @import cloud_firestore;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: Did you forget to add GoogleService-info.plist file to your project? Make sure that you add it properly to the Target

Comment: GoogleService-info.plist is in the project